# How do I use the Mako SDK to detect transparency in a PDF?

Tags: c++, pdf, xps, mako-sdk

I'm using the Mako SDK to analyze my PDF. I'm currently walking through the DOM using:

```
IDOMNode::walkTree(...)
```

But I'm not sure how to tell if the nodes are transparent, or using transparency.

Is there a way to detect transparency in my node tree?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `IRendererTransform` can be used to do this. Basically you set up an `IRendererTransform` to render any transparent content in your node tree. After that, you can then use `probe(...)` to work out if anything would be rendered in that scenario.

This code shows how to do this:

```
IRendererTransformPtr transform = IRendererTransform::create(jawsMako);
transform->renderTransparentNodes(true);

if (transform->probe(<your node tree here>))
{
    // If we get here there is something transparent
}
```

Be aware that in most situations items with zero opacity aren't considered as transparent, as they can be easily discarded.